# How to loop a JQuery function on different HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

Okay so I am trying to create a slide transition when the user hovers on a certain box. I have the function down, but I am wondering is there a way to loop through various different boxes instead of creating a copied function and class with every new slide transition box.

```
//Slide Function-- Start (below)--- 
$("#slide_1").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg1").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg1").slideUp("slow");
});   
//Slide Function--End (above)---
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_2").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg2").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg2").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) --- 
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_3").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg3").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg3").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) ---  
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_4").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg4").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg4").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) --- 
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_5").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg5").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg5").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) ---  
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_6").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg6").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg6").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) --- 
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_7").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg7").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg7").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) --- 
//Slide Function---Start (below) --- 
$("#slide_8").hover(function(){
    $("#slideimg8").slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#slideimg8").slideUp("slow");
});
//Slide Function---End (above) ---
```

So instead of writing a new `slidimg(n)` where **n** is a number, and a new `slide_n` where **n** is a number, is there a way to create a function that will loop somehow.

Sorry if this isn't very straightforward. Pretty new to this type of stuff.

Comment: Can you show add your html in order to guide you on the right way to select elements with a global function

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using `#` id selector.

Create a specific `class` or `attribute` for these components and attach the event handler using the jQuery selector concept rather than creating multiple functions for dynamically created elements.

Take a look at the .[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler attachment which will let you attach event handlers to dynamically added elements if the `selector` is matched.

---

**EDIT**: *Including code snippet for more clarification*

Here is a small example on how to avoid looping:

As seen below, we are using `class` selector to find the `family` of slides and then attaching an handler to it; Here, we don't have to attach the handler to **specific slides** using `#id` selector, as we are selecting them based on their family OR in other words using `class` (`.className`) selector.

Though each slide has an `id` we are not using it as the behavior we are trying to accomplish is the same; **but** if we want one slide to behave differently, we can use it's id (or even we can set attributes to it) to derive uniqueness (and make it behave in a different way based on it's attribute / ID).

```js
/* Using `hover` */

$(".slide").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").slideDown("slow");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("img").slideUp("slow");
  });


/* Using `on` ; Comment the above and un-comment the below to see the same effect */

/*
$(".slide").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('img').slideDown('slow');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find("img").slideUp("slow");
  }
});
*/
```

```css
.slides {
  padding: 10px;
}
.slides > div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="slides">

  <div id="slide_1" class="slide">
    <span>University of Oxford</span>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Oxfordceremony.jpg" alt="Degree Ceremony at University of Oxford" />
  </div>

  <div id="slide_2" class="slide">
    <span>The University of Bologna</span>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Bologna-vista02.jpg/300px-Bologna-vista02.jpg" alt="The University of Bologna" />
  </div>

  <div id="slide_3" class="slide">
    <span>Heidelberg University</span>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Heidelberg_Universit%C3%A4tsbibliothek_2003.jpg/220px-Heidelberg_Universit%C3%A4tsbibliothek_2003.jpg" alt="Heidelberg University" />
  </div>

  <div id="slide_4" class="slide">
    <span>King's College London</span>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Strand102.jpg/220px-Strand102.jpg" alt="King's College London" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to somehow derive some uniqueness between each class element? So they are all part of the same CSS class, but each hover only toggles down a particular element in that class instead of all elements. Is this what on() would do?

Comment: If `slide_1`, `slide_2` .. `slide_n` are going to use the same functionality, it is good to group them into a family (a `class` for example). Each member in that `family` can have different `attributes` though and is possible to have different visualizations.Could you please also put the mark-up (or an image) so that it can be better visualized to solution?

Comment: You should not be avoiding the id selector per say. Rather not be using id's on things that are better suited as classes.